# Closing an app (Dialog Box) with ClientHandler to return to SpreadSheet

Tags: google-apps-script

from a spreadsheet I want to show some information.
The Browser MsgBox is a little too limited; so I want to use an Ui app.
My app is just like dialog box with an OK button.
I found only examples with Server Handler to close the app.
Why I cannot use a Client Handler since I don't have to collect any data? How can I do it?
Thanks, Lauro

Answer (score 0):

UiApp is limited. Cant do that from the client. Use htmlService, it allows what you want.

Comment: That's short... could you explain how you would implement that?

Comment: See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/#serve_html_as_a_google_docs_sheets_or_forms_user_interface

Comment: Additionally see here for how to close a window in htmlservice:  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#closing_dialogs_and_sidebars_in_google_apps