# replicate with a button the x clicking (closing) of a dialog

Tags: google-apps-script

I can't succeed in writing a piece of code with a ClientHandler to close (Cancel) a App opened from a Spreadsheet. 
   I can do it with  a  ServerHandler, but why waiting the call to the server when I don't need to interact with it?
   It seems that clicking on the x to close  (cancel) the dialog uses a Client Handler because it is very fast.
   How can I replicate that behavior?

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned [in another recent post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19757555/closing-an-app-dialog-box-with-clienthandler-to-return-to-spreadsheet) This is not possible from a clientHandler in UiApp.

You should be able to do it with html service (as Zig Mandel stated in his answer) but I didn't test it ([see doc here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#closing_dialogs_and_sidebars_in_google_apps)).